# PowerShell script inside SQL Agent job error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the code below via a script in a SQL agent job on a drive which is failing.  When I logon as the service account user and run it in an ISE shell it works fine which leads me to believe it's not access related.

I tried running it as a PowerShell job step but it wouldn't work so decided to run it as a cmdexec job type and call it like this:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "F:\Powershell\ScriptOutSSRSEncryptionKeys.ps1"
```

**Script**

```
   $ComputerName = "servername"
    $KeyFolder = "\\servername\sharename\SSRSKEYS\"
    $KeyPassword = "Password1"
    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "-yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"
    Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer" -Class                          "__Namespace" -ComputerName $ComputerName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    % {
        $NameSpaceRS = $_
        $InstanceName = $NameSpaceRS.SubString(3)
        $KeyFileName = Join-Path -Path $KeyFolder -ChildPath ($InstanceName +     $Timestamp + ".snk")
         $SQLVersion = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace     "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$($NameSpaceRS)" -Class "__Namespace" -   ComputerName $ComputerName).Name
        $SSRSClass = Get-WmiObject -Namespace    "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$($NameSpaceRS)\$($SQLVersion)\Admin" - Query "SELECT * FROM MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting WHERE   InstanceName='$($InstanceName)'" -ComputerName $ComputerName
        $Key = $SSRSClass.BackupEncryptionKey($KeyPassword)
        If ($Key.HRESULT -ne 0) {
            $Key.ExtendedErrors -join "`r`n" | Write-Error
        } Else {
            $Stream = [System.IO.File]::Create($KeyFileName, $Key.KeyFile.Length)
            $Stream.Write($Key.KeyFile, 0, $Key.KeyFile.Length)
            $Stream.Close()
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
Executed as user: domain\svc_account. Exception calling "Create" with "2" 
argument(s): "Access to the path   '\\servername\sharename\SSRSKEYS\MSSQLSERVER-20150824-125254.snk' is denied."  At 
F:\Powershell\ScriptOutSSRSEncryptionKeys.ps1:24 char:13  +             $Stream = [System.IO.File]::Create($KeyFileName,   $Key.KeyFile.Length ...  +               
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException      + 
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException     You cannot call a 
method on a null-valued expression.  At 
F:\Powershell\ScriptOutSSRSEncryptionKeys.ps1:25 char:13  +             
$Stream.Write($Key.KeyFile, 0, $Key.KeyFile.Length)  +
```

Comment: Sorry for the awful editing of the code this website really needs to help out basic users more!

Comment: I note that the path in the error is missing a leading slash.... maybe nothing. Perhaps as an experiment you could try a local path and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I've tried local paths such as a get-content and strangely enough it works.

Comment: I mean by saying 'it works' doesn't mean it's fixed my issue, more that the account has access to the relevant folder but I can't see why it still complains of access

Comment: Can you now try some other non-ps file operation from within SQL Agent with that user.. like just a DOS file copy.

Comment: It appears that in SQL agent jobs PowerShell runs in a different module, after some more digging around I needed to run powershell.exe -command "path to script here.ps1" and it now works a treat.  I also had to run this as an "Operating System (CmdExec)" job type instead of a PowerShell job type.  

Hopefully this will help anyone else who stumbles across it

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the script path to the `PowerShell.exe` as a parameter using the `&` operator, e.g.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "& 'F:\Powershell\ScriptOutSSRSEncryptionKeys.ps1'"
```

The call operator (`&`) allows you to execute a command, script or function.

**Syntax**

```
& "[path] command" [arguments]
```

Comment: It appears that in SQL agent jobs PowerShell runs in a different module, after some more digging around I needed to run powershell.exe -command "path to script here.ps1" and it now works a treat. I also had to run this as an "Operating System (CmdExec)" job type instead of a PowerShell job type. Hopefully this will help anyone else who stumbles across it